# Is there a way to check if a collection.find returns false using PyMongo?

Tags: python, pymongo, discord.py

I am using PyMongo to make a basic currency bot with discord.py, however, the user can register multiple times into the db.

```
async def register(ctx):
    insert = {"userid":ctx.message.author.id,"cash":0}
    collection.insert_one(insert)
    await ctx.send('okie dokie you are registered')
```

This is the code for the register command, but I'm not sure how to check if a collection.find query returns true or false. Does anybody know how to use it as a check, or any way to check if they are already registered?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `find_one()`, which will either return the obj, or None.

```py
async def register(ctx):
    existing = collection.find_one({"userid": ctx.author.id})
    if not existing:
        # register the user
    else:
        await ctx.send("Sorry, you're already registered.")
```

---

**References:**

- [`collection.find_one()`](https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.find_one) - It states "Returns a single document, or `None` if no matching document is found."